# Recursive function doesn't work despite empty stack test

Tags: python, recursion, indexing, range

I don't know why the line `if len(stack)==0: return 0` doesn't work.

Elements of the graph list represent nodes, for example: `[2, 6]` means that node with value 2 -> node with value 6, similarly node with value 4 is connected to nodes with value 7, 8, 9 (three descendant nodes).

I wonder whether the route from `goal[0]` to `goal[1]` exists or not.

In my example, there is no route.

```
graph_list=[[2, 6], [4, 7], [5, 7], [1, 5], [2, 9], [4, 9], [4, 8], [5, 3], [7, 8]]
goal=[1, 9]

stack=[goal[0],]

def check_func(d_list, goal):

    if len(stack)==0:
        return 0

    for node in d_list:
        if node[0]==stack[-1]:
            stack.append(node[1])
            d_list.remove(node)
            check_func(d_list, goal)

    if stack[-1]==goal[1]:
        return 1

    else:
        stack.pop(-1)
        print(stack)
        check_func(d_list, goal)
```

After some iterations, at the following line, error occur.

> if stack[-1]==goal[1]:
>   IndexError: list index out of range

I don't understand why this error occurs. I think the first line of the function code prevents the error.

Answer (score 2):

I see several problems with your code:

- A common error with recursion beginners: your `check_func()` returns
  a value but when you call it recursively, you ignore the returned
  value!
- Removing items from `d_list` in a loop where you're walking through
  `d_list` is generally a bad idea.  And, in this case, unnecessary.
- Your trial append onto the stack logic is flawed as you don't remove
  the appended item on recursive failure and continue testing.
- Your example `graph_list` will never succeed with goal `[1, 9]` -- a
  useful test case but not great for development.  Instead try a goal
  of `[1, 8]`.

Below is my rework of your code, see if it behaves more the way you desire:

```
def check_func(d_list, goal):

    if not stack:
        return False

    if goal[1] == stack[-1]:
        return True

    for node in d_list:
        if node[0] == stack[-1]:
            stack.append(node[1])
            if check_func(d_list, goal):
                return True
            stack.pop()

    return False

graph_list = [[2, 6], [4, 7], [5, 7], [1, 5], [2, 9], [4, 9], [4, 8], [5, 3], [7, 8]]

goal = [1, 8]

stack = [goal[0]]

if check_func(graph_list, goal):
    print(stack)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[1, 5, 7, 8]
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your careful comment! I learn a lot from you! I understand that the code works following process like this: check_func -> ''if check_func(..)'' return to check_func and at this moment, ''for node in d_list'' same element of the list doesn't repeat (actually, I thought it will repeat so I added ''d_list.remove" line) until no element satisfies the condition ''node[0]==stack[-1]'', when the accident occurs, function return false! and go back to the first one, then implement the line ''stack.pop()'' and repeat! Is this right? If it is right, then I know that what's wrong in my code!

Comment: As you said, the problem in my code was that there was no return except the case some condition hold. Thank you so much! I learned a lot of things from you!